# How to return result of two SELECT statement from a postgres fuunction?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this postgresql function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.test_q1()
 RETURNS TABLE(schemaname text)
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
BEGIN
   return Query (select "content" from public.post where id='863550630468626253');
  -- return Query (select count(*) from public.comments WHERE post_id='863550630468626253');
END
$function$
;
```

How can I return both select statement result from this function?

Is it possible to return the result set of two `select` statement from function such that when i call `public.test_q1` it will return two values first resultset will be the values of `content` and other columns inside first `Select` and second return value will be the count ?

Comment: What do you mean with "two output"? Two rows? Two columns?

Answer (score 1):

Return two values in one query?

```
 select p."content",
        (select count(*)
         from public.comments c
         where c.post_id = '863550630468626253'
        ) as num_comments
 from public.post p
where p.id = '863550630468626253'
            );
```

EDIT:

I don't think you can guarantee the order of results in the returned set of a function, but you can use `union all` to return the two values.  Presumably, `content` is not a number.  So, one method is to cast the values:

```
 select p."content"
 from public.post p
 where p.id = '863550630468626253'
 union all
 select count(*)::text
 from public.comments c
 where c.post_id = '863550630468626253';
```

I believe *in practice* this will return the content first and the count second.  However, I don't think Postgres guarantees the ordering.

Comment: is it possible to return the two `select` statement output from function such that when i call `public.test_q1` it will return two output?

Comment: @manish . . . I don't understand your comment.  Do you want two rows rather than two columns?  If so, use `union all`.